# How to create new column in excel sheet or csv file in chronological order using python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, csv

example  ==> my excel sheet

```
column1    column2    column3
 Movie       Thor       Marvel
 actor        xyz        xyz
  xyz         xyz        xyz
```

now I want to create a new columnx in between column1 and column2 using python

o/p ==> excel or csv sheet

```
column1   columnx     column2    column3
 Movie     newc1        Thor       Marvel
 actor     newc2          xyz        xyz
  xyz      newc3          xyz        xyz
```

Comment: use pandas for solving this question.

Answer (score 1):

You canuse pandas to solve this problem as given below,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': ["Movie", "actor", "xyz"], 'column2': ["Thor", "xyz", "xyz"],'column3': ["Marvel", "xyz", "xyz"]})

df = pd.read_csv("check.csv")

idx = 1
column_x = ["newc1", "newc2", "newc3"]  
df.insert(loc=idx, column='columnx', value=column_x)
df
   column1 columnx column2 column3
0   Movie   newc1    Thor  Marvel
1   actor   newc2     xyz     xyz
2     xyz   newc3     xyz     xyz
```